# How many electrons will eject from a 1 cm diameter metal ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

How many electrons can flow out of a metal ball with $r=1 cm%$ that is under ultra-violet light with wavelength $\lambda=200nm$, the ball wasn't charged beforehand and the output work of the electron is $A_i=3,74eV$

I know that $hv=A_i+\frac{mv^2}{2}$, but I don't know the speed/velocity of the electrons and thus have no way to find that number.

Comment: Welcome in Physics SE.  So did you try to see what energy can have a photon with $\lambda$ wavelength?

Comment: I didn't truth be told, my exams starts in 1h and I have to review all the other topics, so while I know that it isn't such a website I still hoped that someone might point out the solution because I need one ASAP :(

Comment: I see. But this would be called *an automation homework site* and nobody would care about the questions. Better invest your last hour to checking the concepts - sometimes the solution may be easy, if the photon has not enough energy

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For an electron to be emitted, the energy of the photon must afford two things:

1. The energy to remove the electron from the lattice; this is the work function $A_i=3.74{\rm eV}$;
2. The electrostatic binding energy. That is, the $n^{th}$ electron must be removed to infinity from a ball of radius $r_0 = 10{\rm cm}$ to infinity, when the latter has a charge of $+(n-1)\,e$. So this calls for energy $\frac{1}{4\,\pi\,\epsilon_0}\frac{(n-1)\,e}{r_0}$.

So, the equation of the available energy $h\,\nu$ to the sum of these two will give you an equation for $n$ when the incoming photons are barely unable to separate electrons from the ball.